# Question about Fourier series/coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that you have a function $f \in L^2[0,1]$, then by simple use of Bessel's Inequality we know that $$\hat{f}(n) = ( f,e^{2 \pi i nx})= \int_0^1 f(x)e^{-2 \pi i nx} \, dx \rightarrow0,$$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. From here we see that the real and imaginary part of this integral are equal to each other, that is
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f(x) \cos(2 \pi nx) \, dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} i\int_0^1 f(x) \sin(2 \pi nx) \, dx.$$ I am wondering how we can actually compute each of these limits. If I had to guess I would say the limit of these things would be $0$, but how can I prove this explicitly?
Thank!

Comment: Do you know that a complex sequence approaches $0$ iff the real and imaginary part approach $0$?

Comment: @DionelJaime: Thank you for your answer, yes I am aware of this however $f$ need not be real-valued. Does this affect the approach?

Comment: $f$ and, in particular $\hat{f}$ are complex valued. $\hat{f}$ approaching $0$ means its real and imaginary parts (which are the two integrals you're asking about) approaches $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^{1} \Re f(x) \cos (2\pi nx)dx\to 0$ because it is the real part of  $\int_0^{1} \Re f(x) e^{2\pi nx} dx$ and $\Re f$ is itself an $L^{2}$ function. Similarly,  $\int_0^{1} \Im f(x) \cos (2\pi nx)dx\to 0$ so we get  $\int_0^{1}  f(x) \cos (2\pi nx)dx\to 0$. Thus, both the limits are $0$.

Comment: I did prove it for complex valued $f$. $\Re f$ is my notation for  the real part of $f$ and $\Im f$ is my notation for  the imaginary part of $f$. @HrafnMagnus

Comment: I see, sorry for misunderstanding the notation. Thank you.